# Javascript rotate on mouse-down drag

Tags: javascript, html, animation, rotation, drag

Im trying to make a spinning wheel rotate when dragging the mouse on it. The wheel is formed by 3 pieces so I mapped each image independently in order to target the section of the wheel which I want to rotate. Right now it is working pretty good. The only problem being that im using event.clientX for the rotation parameter and it can be kinda random at times, sometimes the wheel moves to a random angle on start but for the most part it works. I would just like a formula to feed a better rotation parameter to my script. Here is the code I currently have:

```
var isDragging      = false;

var innerWheelActive    = false;
var middleWheelActive   = false;
var outerWheelActive    = false;

$(document).ready(function() {



    /*------------------------------------------*/

    $("#mapping map #middleArea").mousedown(function() {
            isDragging  = true;
            middleWheelActive   = true;

            return false;
    });

    $("#mapping map #innerArea").mousedown(function() {
            isDragging  = true;
            innerWheelActive    = true;

            return false;
    });

    $("#mapping map #outerArea").mousedown(function() {
            isDragging  = true;
            outerWheelActive    = true;

            return false;
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
        if (isDragging) {       

            var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + event.clientX + 'deg)';
            if(innerWheelActive)
                $('#innerWheel img').css({ '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS });
            else if(middleWheelActive)
                $('#middleWheel img').css({ '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS });
            else if(outerWheelActive)
                $('#outerWheel img').css({ '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS });

            return false;
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        if (isDragging){
            console.log('stopped');
            isDragging  = false;
            innerWheelActive    = false;
            middleWheelActive   = false;
            outerWheelActive    = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: [Does it help you](http://ammarshaikh.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/drag-object-in-circular-motion-using-jquery-ui-draggable/)

Comment: with regards to your edit, it may work better if you spell "dragging" correctly -- "gragging" in `mouseup`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to add event.preventDefault and event.stopPorpagation in your callback function :

```
$('img').draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui){
        var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';
        $(this).css({ '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS });
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: tried it, it did two things, 1st it moved it to some random point but it remained there, 2nd it no longer rotates on drag just on click :( Im guessing that preventing default stops the drag tracking?

Answer (score -1):

Your logic has a problem, it relies solely on x ordinate which does not always increase when you rotate things.

Try this instead. It calculates the distance moved my mouse from initial point and thus considers both the x and y coordinates. It should work fine.

```
function getDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.sqrt((x1-x2) * (x1-x2) + (y2-y1) * (y2-y1));
}
var div = $("#mydiv");
var rotation = 0; 
var isDragging = false;
div.mousedown(function(event) {
    isDragging = true;
    lastX = event.clientX;
    lastY = event.clientY;
}).mouseup(function(event) {
    isDragging = false;
}).mousemove(function(event) {
    if (isDragging) {
        var curX = event.clientX;
        var curY = event.clientY;   
        rotation += getDistance(curX,curY,lastX,lastY); 
        var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)';
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
        });  
        lastX = curX;
        lastY = curY;
    }
})
```

​

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/AM5tU/)

Comment: It should, as its jQuery. Why dont you test it ?

Comment: I tested it on desktop and it was really bad, the wheel would move but in a very choppy way. I just edited my main post so you can see what I currently have which works at the moment it just needs some refining calculating the rotation. I tried your post with last and current coordinates and like I said it just didnt work too well.

Comment: @CarlosR.Batista, I've edited my code. It works smoothly as you wanted.

Comment: it spins to the right but it refuses to spin to the left. I noticed that if I remove the last two lines of code in your code and it does spin back and forth but when I drag the mouse back the point where I first clicked before dragging it reverts the direction of the rotation for some reason. Im thinking this is happening because the calculated distance is always positive? So when I go back to point 0,0 which instead of getting negatives values it keeps throwing positive ones. Maybe the distance script needs to supply a negative value when you counter rotate? I dont know im still stuck

Comment: @CarlosR.Batista, distances are never negative. Finding a way to predict the direction of mouse movement is little bit tough and tricky too. Cant we constraint the mouse movement ?

Comment: ya i know distances are supposed to be positive, it just doesnt help me if it always is. Its a spinning wheel so I have to be able to spin right and also left.

Comment: I cannot think of a way by which I can predict the direction of mouse movement.Suppose if we assume 4 quadrants in my circle (0,0 as center of circle).Now,clientX & clientY decreases in first quadrant (for ACW direction but clientX and clienty decreases in third quandrant (for CW direction).Thus, by looking at point, we cannot predict the direction of mouse movement. But yes, if you can constraint the mouse movement to first quadrant only, we can predict the direction.In nutshell,if you say that dragging can only be start with the place where `hello` is written, we can predict direction.

Comment: I can now if the mouse is moving the left by simply comparing currentX and previousX. Depending on whether one is greater than the other it can definitely tell me which way the mouse is moving, however when I try to minus that distance to rotate it just doesnt look good. I guess it needs more math involved in some way.

Comment: If you move mouse from up to down, there's no change in X position . Also, if currentX is greater than previousX, it will be clockwise when moving on top of circle, but anticlockwise at bottom of circle :) Think again closely. Also, we need both X and Y position and too is not enough here

Comment: well i dont care about rotation when y changes, i only care about x now that i think about it. So ignoring y is a non-issue.

Comment: @CarlosR.Batista, Read again ` if currentX is greater than previousX, it will be clockwise when moving on top of circle, but anticlockwise at bottom of circle`.Also, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/AM5tU/1/), its exactly as you asked (ignoring Y) but it wont work when you move mouse up to down and will work in reverse direction when you move mouse at bottom of circle. I hope this should clear you logic

Comment: thats the thing though, I never have to interact with the bottom area of the circle only the top.

Comment: Doesn't properly work. Lacks the math (it is only partial => this is why is only spins to the right)

Comment: @Symba, yeah. It doesnt properly work. As I've mentioned in comments that it's not possible to predict the direction by x and y position only.